# bootstrap show.bs.modal event won't fire

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with my modal events. None of them I tested worked.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 and I tested my code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp0rjc03/) and everything is working well there.

Here's my js :

`$('#delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var title = $(e.relatedTarget).data('title');
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    document.getElementById('id').value = id;
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
 });`

I have no errors in my console, the modal shows up but the event isn't fired. I've tried show, shown and loaded.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is #delete the id of the container you have your modal wired up to?

Comment: #delete is the id of my modal but I resolved the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before asking this question, I haven't tested the .modal('show) method. 
I got an error and after few checkups it's because I had two different versions of Jquery.

Problem solved after removing one.